# Where can I define the language in CUEDthesisPSnPDF files?

Tags: languages, spanish

I downloaded some files to build my thesis document from this site http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/. I have a problem, where can I define the spanish language to get titles in spanish. I tried to declare it in the `CUEDthesisPSnPDF.cls` file with `usepackage[spanish]{babel}`, but it doesn't work.
I'd like to get your help.

Comment: Have you tried in your preambel: `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`?

Comment: Are you sure that `classicthesis` is compatible with that class? It can work only with classes based on `scrbook` or `screprt` and I don't think it's good with your custom class.

Comment: @egreg You're right, i've changed the question.

Answer (score 6):

If you really need to use that buggy class, you have to edit it.

Make a copy, call it `myCUEDthesis.cls` and change the first lines, that originally reads (with line numbers added for clarity)

```
  1 %
  2 % CUEDthesis v1.1
  3 % By Harish Bhanderi <harish.bhanderi@cantab.net
  4 % Version 1.0 released 15/07/2002
  5 % Version 1.1 released 14/07/2010
  6 %-------------------------- identification ---------------------
  7 %\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
  8 \ProvidesClass{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}[2010/07/14 v1.1 CUED thesis class]
  9 %-------------------------- initial code -----------------------
 10 \newif\ifCU@bookmode
 11 \CU@bookmodetrue
 12 
 13 \DeclareOption{report}{\CU@bookmodefalse}
 14 \DeclareOption{book}{\CU@bookmodetrue}
 15 \ProcessOptions\relax%
 16 
 17 \ifCU@bookmode
 18 \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}%
 19 \ProcessOptions\relax%
 20 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined%
 21    \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{book}%
 22 \else%
 23    \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{book}%
 24 \fi%
 25 \else
 26 \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}%
 27 \ProcessOptions\relax%
 28 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined%
 29   \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{report}%
 30 \else%
 31    \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{report}%
 32 \fi%
 33 %\renewcommand{\refname}{References}%
 34 \fi
 35 
 36 %\DeclareOption{book}{%
 37 %}%
 38 \usepackage{setspace}
 39 \usepackage{tocbibind}
 40 \usepackage{amssymb}
 41 %\usepackage{graphicx}
 42 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 43 \usepackage{eucal}
 44 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 45 \usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
 46 \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
 47 \usepackage[square, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
 48 \usepackage{ifthen}
 49 \usepackage{ifpdf}
```

to the following

```
% CUEDthesis v1.1 with modifications by Isai
%%%%%%%
% By Harish Bhanderi <harish.bhanderi@cantab.net
% Version 1.0 released 15/07/2002
% Version 1.1 released 14/07/2010
%-------------------------- identification ---------------------
%\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myCUEDthesis}[2013/01/26 v1.1m CUED thesis class]
%-------------------------- initial code -----------------------
\newif\ifCU@bookmode
\CU@bookmodetrue

\DeclareOption{report}{\CU@bookmodefalse}
\DeclareOption{book}{\CU@bookmodetrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax%

\ifCU@bookmode
  \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
  \ProcessOptions\relax
  \LoadClass[a4paper]{book}
\else
  \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
  \ProcessOptions\relax
  \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{report}
\fi
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[square, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
```

Then you'll be able to say in your document

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{Classes/myCUEDthesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %%% use the actual input encoding
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

One might also use the original class and say

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,spanish]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}
```

starting the document with

```
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
```

However it not recommendable, in my opinion, to load `babel` in a class file, because it's a typical user setting. Moreover, the part I've modified is really buggy in the original, because it will *never* select DVI output, but always setup the document for PDF output.

Every construction like

```
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
```

is *wrong*, because `\pdfoutput` *is* defined in all cases (at least if the TeX distribution is less than five years old, approximately).